# multisite or multi install?

Tags: 7, multi-sites

I am planning a Drupal 7 site for video sharing, where registered users can share videos.

Main Site: example.com
Subdomain for blog for registered users would be: blog.example.com.

The database would be different for main site and subdomain. Since the target of main site would be very high traffic, what would be the efficient choice ? either Multisite or Multiple Drupal installation (one installation for Main and another installation for blog) ?

what would you advice and why ? (I mean from personal experience, difficulty to handle and maintain, performance issues, etc)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your choice of site architecture (e.g. multisite or multiple drupal installations) doesn't necessarily play into performance. Meaning any site can be made performant using the right mix of modules (memcache, Varnish on the front end, etc.);

With that in mind, look at the following criteria when selecting multisite over multi-installation instead:

- Will most of the modules on the sites be shared with one another?
- Related, will the modules always be in sync via version? i.e. Context 3 vs. Context 2.
- Will the versions need to be in sync? i.e. If you upgrade the main site, will the blog site also need to be upgraded?

If the answer to any of these questions is yes, use a multisite. If there is concern about them, use two document roots with one site a piece. Sharing content can easily be done through any of the following projects so multisite or multi-installation doesn't matter:

- http://drupal.org/project/feeds
- http://drupal.org/project/migrate
- http://drupal.org/project/services

Comment: I guess the performance matters, since, the site would focus more on the video sharing. Blog is not so important aspect, its just added service. So, I would not want to compromise the performance of main site, but blog's performance would come only as second priority.

Comment: Good then we're on the same page. What I was referring to here was that multisite vs. multiinstall doesn't have a performance benefit one way or the other. The only time that isn't true is when content reaches into the high hundreds of thousands and even then switching away from a MySQL backend to something like MongoDB would be in order.

Comment: I got the point !!!